# filter list via linq

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I have a list as follows (EN is you can say the default value)

> id="1", lang="FR", value="text1FR"
>   id="1", lang="EN", value="text1EN"
>   id="2", lang="EN", value="text2EN"
>   id="3", lang="FR", value="text3FR"
>   id="3", lang="EN", value="text3EN"

is there a way to filter this list via linq to get this result?
(take FR if it's there, else take EN which is always there)

> id="1", lang="FR", value="text1FR"
>   id="2", lang="EN", value="text2EN"
>   id="3", lang="FR", value="text3FR"

Comment: It is always better if you show your effort so far. This will reduce the likeliness of downvoting and enables us to teach you what the problems are with your solution instead of just giving you a solution you might not understand.

Comment: @BojanSkrchevski: Apart from the fact that OP should have shown what he has tried, your comment is not really helpful. If someone takes the time to learn what he doesn't know yet, he wouldn't need to ask a question on SO at all.

Comment: @BojanSkrchevski: If it would be homework he wouldn't ask for a linq approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.id)
    .Select(g => g.Any(x => x.lang=="FR") 
                 ? g.First(x => x.lang=="FR")
                 : g.First(x => x.lang=="EN"));
```

This is more efficient:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.id)
    .Select(g => g.Where(x => x.lang == "FR")
                  .DefaultIfEmpty(g.First(x => x.lang == "EN"))
                  .First());
```